# Is it possible to push categories of woocommerce products to trash or make them as "drafts" instead of deleting?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I work with woocommerce and sometimes i do not want to delete category with products, but to make it temporary not visible on website.

So i want to change the status of category as "draft" or move it to trash, but do not permanently delete. I can do such thing with products, but not with categories. Is there a plugin/any solution in wp to achieve this?

I googled a lot, but no luck.

Comment: What did you google, here first hit: https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-categories-products-woocommerce/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not what i need. There are some modules on website, that shows categories with their images (OUTSIDE the shop pages), and i do not want to show "draft" or "trash" categories. If i will use the plugin you suggested, it will only hide the categories INSIDE shop page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "module", but if you are referencing to the `[product_categories]` shortcode from WooCommerce, put this into your functions.php in your (child) theme. Tested and works.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories', 'custom_woocommerce_product_categories_filter' );
function custom_woocommerce_product_categories_filter( $terms )
{
    foreach( $terms as $key => $term )
    {
        if( $term->slug == "trash" || $term->slug == "draft" ) unset($terms[$key]);
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i add statuses like "published/draft"  to my product categories? When i go to the list of product categories, there are no "status" option with "published/draft/etc" properties. This is my problem

Comment: You could code that but why? These categories are only internal, so you can just use the slug for this. If you want it more dynamic, you could use the above code and instead of `$term->slug == "draft"` you can check if the slug contains a string. Like this: `str_contains($term->slug, "draft")`. Then, you can use any slug which contains "draft" like "draft_to_be_revised", "draft_ready" etc. Works only with PHP8, for PHP7 you will need a [polyfill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php#125977).